# Calculate the 85th percentile for yAxis in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, percentile

I have a chart with multiple series for which I have a button that resets the yAxis to a specific amount. I would like to set this specific amount to be the 85th percentile of the yAxis values. Is there a way to calculate this?
jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/inadcod/TynwP/

Comment: Set the yAxis to 85th percentile meaning what? You only want to view items above that percentile? This question is not very clear.

Comment: What does `yAxis to 85th percentile` mean ? Do you want to recalculate all your serie data or only show 85% of the max on the yAxis labels ?

Comment: What I want is to display the items below and up to the 85th percentile. I found a way to calculate the percentile here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile. Basically, I have to get all the values of the yAxis, sort them from lowest to highest, and get the entire number of all the values. The idea is that I don't know how to get all the values from the yAxis and how to sort them.

Comment: Actually you don't need the values of the yAxis, but of your chartdata! You have this data right before you push it into the chart, so just loop through your data.

Comment: @LeJared - can you show me how to do this?

Comment: Show you what? Looping through your data or doing the math for calculating a 85th percentile? The first is trivial, if you know, how to use a for-loop (every thing else goes far beyond this question). The second i can't tell you. Ask for help here http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @inadcod You don't have to do it by javascript, do it on your backend and pass the serie to highcharts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very strange that you wish to do this on the client, you could very easily sort and get the value of the 85th percentile on the server where you are actually sending the data from and use it as a max value for the y axis.

Anyway, you can access the data values using the `series.points` object array, this contains all the points for the given series, it has many properties of which `point.y` seems to be of your interest. Loop through all these and store them in another array for convenience and sort this new array. take the length of the array and multiple by the factor you wish to (0.85) and this is the index of the element a.k.a. 85th percentile. Set the min of the given yAxis using this value

```
var yData = [];
$.each(chart.series[0].points, function() {
    yData.push(this.y);
});
var sortedY = sort(yData);
var eightyFifthPercentile = sortedY[Math.floor(sortedY.length * 0.85)];

alert(eightyFifthPercentile);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/HkS2Y/

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have to do it on the client as it is the way it was requested. I hope I will be able to implement it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
var yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];
var extremes = yAxis.getExtremes();
yAxis.setExtremes(extremes.min, extremes.dataMax * 0.85);
```

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/gyavJ/

Comment: This takes the display up to the 85 percent of the chart. I added a comment above about how the percentile is calculated. Anyway, thanks for the answer.